# Dotted Seaborn distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have a seaborn displot which looks like this
[image]

I want to make some lines as dotted. How can I achieve this ?
I tried to use linestyle in 2 different ways and got error

```
#### approach 1
for x, m in x_list:
    sns.distplot(x, hist=False, label=m, linestyle='--')
#### approach 2
for x, m in x_list:
    sns.distplot(x, hist=False, label=m, kde_kws={'linestyle':'--'})

TypeError: distplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linestyle'
```

Answer (score 5):

The second approach using `kde_kws={'linestyle':'--'}` works fine with seaborn 8.1. Maybe you want to update.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_list = [np.random.rayleigh(1+i/2., size=35) for i in range(4)]

for x in x_list:
    sns.distplot(x, hist=False, kde_kws={'linestyle':'--'})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have 7.1. Due to restrictions, I can't upgrade but thanks for the pointer

Comment: Seaborn does not have any restrictions. It's pure python. You can install it with pip or download it from GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of the Line2D objects from the axes returned by the seaborn distplot using `ax.lines`. Then, loop through these objects using [`set_linesytle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle) in order to set the desired linestyle.

For example:

```
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x, hist=False)

[line.set_linestyle("--") for line in ax.lines] 

plt.show()
```

[image]