# How to set a different linestyle for each hue group in a kdeplot / displot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, displot, kdeplot

- How can each `hue` group of a [`seaborn.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html), or [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) with `kind='kde'` be given a different `linestyle`?

  - Both axes-level and figure-level options will accept a `str` for `linestyle/ls`, which applies to all `hue` groups.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load sample data
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

# convert data to long form
im = iris.melt(id_vars='species')

# axes-level plot works with 1 linestyle
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
p1 = sns.kdeplot(data=im, x='value', hue='variable', fill=True, ls='-.')

# figure-level plot works with 1 linestyle
p2 = sns.displot(kind='kde', data=im, x='value', hue='variable', fill=True, ls='-.')
```

- `kdeplot`

[image]

- `displot`

[image]

### Reviewed Questions

- [How to set the line style for each kdeplot in a jointgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49671053/7758804) doesn't deal with `hue` groups.
- [How to automatically alternate or cycle linestyles in seaborn regplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55461832/7758804) doesn't deal with `hue` groups and iterates through each unique group.
- [Dotted Seaborn distplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49545409/7758804) doesn't deal with `hue` groups and iterates through each unique group.
- [change line style in seaborn facet grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44261803/7758804) `hue_kws` isn't a valid option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- With `fill=True` the object to update is in `.collections`
- With `fill=False` the object to update is in `.lines`
- Updating the legend is fairly simple:

  - `handles = p.legend_.legendHandles[::-1]` extracts and reverses the legend handles. They're reversed to update because they're in the opposite order in which the plot `linestyle` is updated
  - Note that figure-level plots extract the legend with `._legend`, with the axes-level plots use `.legend_`.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### `kdeplot`: axes-level

- Extract and iterate through `.collections` or `.lines` from the `axes` object and use `.set_linestyle`

#### `fill=True`

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
p = sns.kdeplot(data=im, x='value', hue='variable', fill=True)

lss = [':', '--', '-.', '-']

handles = p.legend_.legendHandles[::-1]

for line, ls, handle in zip(p.collections, lss, handles):
    line.set_linestyle(ls)
    handle.set_ls(ls)
```

[image]

#### `fill=False`

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
p = sns.kdeplot(data=im, x='value', hue='variable')

lss = [':', '--', '-.', '-']

handles = p.legend_.legendHandles[::-1]

for line, ls, handle in zip(p.lines, lss, handles):
    line.set_linestyle(ls)
    handle.set_ls(ls)
```

[image]

### `displot`: figure-level

- Similar to the axes-level plot, but each axes must be iterated through
- The legend `handles` could be updated in `for line, ls, handle in zip(ax.collections, lss, handles)`, but that applies the update for each subplot. Therefore, a separate loop is created to update the legend `handles` only once.

#### `fill=True`

```py
g = sns.displot(kind='kde', data=im, col='variable', x='value', hue='species', fill=True, common_norm=False, facet_kws={'sharey': False})

axes = g.axes.flat

lss = [':', '--', '-.']

for ax in axes:
    for line, ls in zip(ax.collections, lss):
        line.set_linestyle(ls)
        
handles = g._legend.legendHandles[::-1]
for handle, ls in zip(handles, lss):
    handle.set_ls(ls)
```

[image]

#### `fill=False`

```py
g = sns.displot(kind='kde', data=im, col='variable', x='value', hue='species', common_norm=False, facet_kws={'sharey': False})

axes = g.axes.flat

lss = [':', '--', '-.']

for ax in axes:
    for line, ls in zip(ax.lines, lss):
        line.set_linestyle(ls)
        
handles = g._legend.legendHandles[::-1]
for handle, ls in zip(handles, lss):
    handle.set_ls(ls)
```

[image]