# How to change line width of a KDE plot in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I can't change the tickness of the kde line in seaborn.

[image]

Here is the line of the code:

```
sns.kdeplot(ax=ax2,x=dots['Longitude'],y=dots['Latitude'],kde_kws={'linestyle':':'},lw=0.1,levels=10)
```

Is it missing something?

Comment: [How to set a different linestyle for each hue group in a kdeplot / displot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70089199/7758804)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the plural form:

```
geyser = sns.load_dataset("geyser")
sns.kdeplot(data=geyser, x="waiting", y="duration", linestyles='--', linewidths=0.5)
```

Output:

[image]